# What will be the Hadoop Streaming Run Command to access the files in the Sub Directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I have written a mapper program in python for hadoop Map-Reduce framework.

And I am executing it through the command:

`hadoop jar /usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar -mapper "python wordcount_mapper.py" -file wordcount_mapper.py -input inputfile -output outputfile3`

It is working properly if the directory **inputfile** contains only file.

But it is not working and showing error if there is sub directories into the directory **inputfile** . Like i have two sub directory in (KAKA and KAKU) in **inputfile**.

And the error is showing :

> 16/07/20 17:01:40 ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Error Launching job : Not
>   a file: hdfs://secondary/user/team/inputfile/kaka

So, My question is that what will be the command to reach the files into the Sub Directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regular expressions:

`inputfile/*`   - will work for 1 level of sub directories

`inputfile/*/*` - will work for 2 level of sub directories

Run As:

`hadoop jar /usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar -mapper "python wordcount_mapper.py" -file wordcount_mapper.py -input inputfile/* -output outputfile3`